# Generating a simple term.matrix from a dataframe

Tags: r

I have an R data.frame of the form:

```
           name masterchef newsnight shameless
1  charliesheen        202       118       235
2 JohnBishop100        209        95       196
3     rioferdy5        195       152       274
```

and I would like to use the R wordcloud commonality.cloud and comparison.cloud routines to compare the column values. The *.cloud routines take a term.matrix rather than a data,.frame such as the above, so how can I trasnform my original data.frame to a term.matrix?

Comment: `commonality.cloud` does not appear to be a function that  RSiteSearch() is able to find.

Comment: It is apparently a very, very new version of the wordcloud package, which is not on all mirrors yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code seems to work. The key thing to realize is that `term.matrix` is not a type of object. Instead, it is the name of an argument which expects to be passed a `matrix` object consisting of the word frequencies.

(One more note: in preparing that matrix, make sure that the `name` column from your data frame ends up in the matrix's dimnames attribute, instead of in its body.)

```
# Create the example data.frame
df <- read.table(text = "name masterchef newsnight shameless
charliesheen        202       118       235
JohnBishop100        209        95       196
rioferdy5        195       152       274", header=TRUE)

# Convert the frequency columns to a matrix, 
# and use the 'name' column as its row names
mat <- as.matrix(df[-1])
dimnames(mat)[1] <- df[1]

# Check that it works
library(wordcloud)
commonality.cloud(term.matrix = mat)
```